# Does jQuery's on() support this kind of livequery feature?

Tags: jquery

With livequery I can do the following:

```
$(".focusable").livequery(function() {
   $(this).focus();
});
```

I know that jQuery supports custom functions for delegates and the like but I'm not seeing anything that makes me think that jQuery can do what livequery is doing in this example.

```
$("body").on("???", ".focusable", function() {
   $(this).focus();
});
```

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: What is `livequery` doing in this example?

Comment: Makes sense to me because I've used [livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) a lot, but if you provide a more specific code example and present a real problem, it will make more sense to others as well.

Comment: Apparently it auto executes the function as soon s a matching element is added

Comment: I'm not sure how this example isn't a real problem.  It is my exact code that I need to work.

Comment: So `livequery` just runs a loop that checks for the existence of specific elements every twenty milliseconds (that seems to be hard-coded into the source). If you want to mimic `DOMNodeInserted` in old browsers, using the plugin is your best bet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `DOMNodeInserted` event:

```
$("body").on("DOMNodeInserted", ".focusable", function() {
   $(this).focus();
});
```

This is not supported by IE8 and older: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference

Comment: IE8 is still very much a prominently used browser so this is perhaps inadequate for the real world, but this is interesting nonetheless.

Comment: I'm marking this as the correct answer.  I actually decided to approach this in a different way, however.  The elements I needed to have focus show up in a modal dialog (bootstrap from twitter) and so I used it's "shown" event to trigger my focus() call.

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not supported vie standard jQuery. Generally the jQuery event to use would be `load`:

> The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have
>   been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element
>   associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the
>   window object.

However it cannot be used with `live` / `delegate` and most likely `on`:

> Note: The .live() and .delegate() methods cannot be used to detect the
>   load event of an iframe. The load event does not correctly bubble up
>   the parent document and the event.target isn't set by Firefox, IE9 or
>   Chrome, which is required to do event delegation.

So until this is fixed, you will have to stick with `livequery`, they apparently employ a workaround to make this possible.

For more info see here:
http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: I believe, however, that the element has to support the load event itself.  So for IMG tags and the like this makes sense.  There is a "loading" process.  But for things like input elements, it does not work.