# jQuery how to translate livequery to on?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, livequery, jquery-on

I have this code which works however it is using a old legacy function "livequery" which should really be switched to using "on".  However for the life of me I can't get this to work.
Here is my code snippet.

```
jQuery('.box').livequery(function(){
     jQuery('a', this).click(function() {
          return false;
     });
     jQuery(this).draggable({
        appendTo: "body",
        helper: 'clone',
        opacity: 0.5,
        zIndex: 900,
        stop: function(event, ui) {
        return true;
        }           
     });
});
```

And I tried this...

```
jQuery('.box').on('draggable', function(){
     jQuery('a', this).click(function() {
          return false;
     });
     jQuery(this).draggable({
        appendTo: "body",
        helper: 'clone',
        opacity: 0.5,
        zIndex: 900,
        stop: function(event, ui) {
        return true;
        }           
     });
});
```

That didn't work as I am guessing "draggable" isn't the event name...

Thanks..

Comment: `livequery != live`, so turning code that uses `livequery` to use `on` may not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

This answer over there [New Inserted dom node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691916/does-jquerys-on-support-this-kind-of-livequery-feature) may help you to convert your code into on functionality instead of live function